# why am not able to view to complete text in my app

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F3E889"
    android:paddingLeft="100dp"
    android:paddingTop="100dp"
    android:paddingEnd="100dp"
    android:paddingRight="100dp"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName4"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:ems="100"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="I want to be a Android developer"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-64dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-46dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is simple code which is trying to print I want to be a Android developed but when viewed on
mobile its not showing the complete sentence.

Comment: Change your constraints values.

Answer (score 1):

May be you don't give a proper constraints to your editText also you don't give a proper padding to your parent layout, please try this code :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#F3E889"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:visibility="visible"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName4"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         android:inputType="textPersonName"
         android:text="I want to be a Android developer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's 100 dp of padding on all 4 sides. That pushes all the content to the middle of the screen. It cuts off like half of the usable space.